# ¿Como saber que imagen tengo en un ImageView?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy realizando un juego en android donde aparecen imagenes aleatoriamente y el usuario tiene que poner el nombre de la imagen en ingles, pero tengo un problema al momento de comparar la imagen para que esta concuerde con el nombre, las imagenes estan en un arreglo y se van mostrando aleatoriamente. El problema es que nunca entra a el if cuando el nombre y la imagen concuerdan.

```
    String[] nombres={"cabbage","bettrot","broccoli","carrot","cauliflower","celery","cucumber","garlic","lettuce","onion","potato","radish","tomato"};


    private static final
    Integer[] verduras ={
            R.drawable.cabbage,
            R.drawable.bettrot,
            R.drawable.broccoli,
            R.drawable.carrot,
            R.drawable.cauliflower,
            R.drawable.celery,
            R.drawable.cucumber,
            R.drawable.garlic,
            R.drawable.lettuce,
            R.drawable.onion,
            R.drawable.potato,
            R.drawable.radish,
            R.drawable.tomato,
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main5);

        mIma =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.alea);
        mIma.setImageResource(verduras[generar.nextInt(verduras.length)]);

       // mNombre=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.nombre);


        mVer=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnverificar);

        mVer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int aciertos,errores;
                EditText repollo =((EditText)findViewById(R.id.nombre));

                mIma.setImageResource(verduras[generar.nextInt(verduras.length)]);


                    if (repollo.getText().equals("cabbage") && mIma.equals(R.drawable.cabbage)) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correcto" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        aciertos = 1;

                    }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Podrias` agregar un TAG en el `ImageView` para identificar la imagen cargada usando el método setTag():

```
mIma =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.alea);
mIma.setImageResource(verduras[generar.nextInt(verduras.length)]);
mIma.setTag("cauliflower");
```

y posteriormente obtener que imagen esta cargada mediante `getTag()`:

```
String nombreImagen = (String) mIma.getTag();
```

---

podrías agregar otro array con las descripciones:

```
String[] verdurasText ={
        "cabbage",
        "bettrot",
        "broccoli",
        "carrot",
        "cauliflower",
        "celery",
        "cucumber",
        "garlic",
        "lettuce",
        "onion",
        "potato",
        "radish",
        "tomato",
};
```

y agregar el Tag (etiqueta) de esta forma :

```
...
mIma =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.alea);
int indexVerdura = generar.nextInt(verduras.length)
mIma.setImageResource(verduras[indexVerdura]);
mIma.setTag(verdurasTexto[indexVerdura]); //Agrega etiqueta.
...
```